# Jquery get width/height after adjustment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the width or height (depending on the size of a screen) of a image after it's been resized. It's for a gallery and I'm trying to make the outer div to wrap tightly around it however it's not getting the size of image, it's only getting 0px. The value it's trying to get is set as "auto" in CSS so why can't it get the actual value after that's been set?

Any ideas? Here's what I've got at the moment.

**Javascript:**

```
function resizeDiv() {
vpw = $(window).width();
vph = $(window).height();
$("#image_holder_main").css({"height": (vph - 30) + "px", "width" : (vpw - 30) + "px"});
if(vpw > vph){
    $("#image_main").css({"height": (vph - 30) + "px", "width" : "auto"});
    $("#image_large").css({"height": (vph - 30) + "px", "width" : $("#image_main").outerWidth() + "px"});
}else if(vph > vpw){
    $("#image_main").css({"height": "auto", "width" : (vpw - 30) + "px"});
    $("#image_large").css({"height": $("#image_main").outerHeight() + "px", "width" : (vpw - 30) + "px"});
}
//$("#image_large").css({"height": $("#image_main").outerHeight() + "px", "width" : $("#image_main").outerWidth() + "px"});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="image_large">
        <section id="image">
            <header id="image_large_head">
                <div id="close_image"><a href="#" id="but_close_image">X</a></div>
            </header>
            <div id="image_holder_main">
                <img src="http://theteakman.co.uk/images/decks/Sunseeker/IMG_0166.JPG" id="image_main" title="Boat Picture">
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#image_large{
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#image_holder_main{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please include your HTML and CSS.

Comment: It should work. If your images are not hidden.

Comment: The image is the correct size, but in the case of the desktop with a wide screen the containing div has a width of 0px when it should be the width of the image.

Comment: can't get dimensions of elements that are hidden ... they have no dimensions as far as browser is concerned

Comment: But it's not hidden - it is visible. It's made to display block before the function is called - sorry didn't add that.